# Android Facebook SDK | How to get day of birth

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, profile, date

I managed to get the first_name, last_name and the link_uri. I am not sure how to get the user's date of birth.

This is the code I used in my loginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            }
        };

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                nextActivity(newProfile);
            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        profileTracker.startTracking();


        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                nextActivity(profile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            }
        };
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Facebook login
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        nextActivity(profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Facebook login
        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        //Facebook login
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    }

    private void nextActivity(Profile profile) {
        if (profile != null) {
            Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("name", profile.getFirstName());
            main.putExtra("surname", profile.getLastName());
            main.putExtra("imageUrl", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString());
            startActivity(main);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show the age of the user in the next activity so do I also need to do something with the returned value? (I assume it would be something like dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: You need to ask the user for the necessary permission first. Plus, RTM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to submit you application to review on facebook developer console or
create test developer for the app. and for those account ask for permission of "date of birth" while running code, you will get dob for those test developer